Como eliminar filas con la condición de dígitos iguales?
Estoy con R y quiero eliminar las filas que tengan digitos iguales en una columna, como pondría la condición?
MLMAR <- MLMAR[!(MLMAR$COVERED_AREA < 25) | (MLMAR$TOTAL_AREA < 25), ]


Hola ! bienvenido, has un ejemplo ? Que has intentado?

Buenos días, ya agrego un código que estuve usando para eliminar otras filas. Busco mas que nada como poner la condición de dígitos iguales, por ejemplo 1111 o 2222. Si saben de otra forma para eliminar filas, me serviría mucho.

Ok, puesta al dia tu codigo poniendo los datos que has utilisado hasta hoy para que el ejemplo sea mínimo y reproducible

Perdon, no entiendo

Para eliminar las filas que tengan dígitos iguales en una columna en R, puedes utilizar expresiones regulares. Suponiendo que quieres eliminar las filas donde los dígitos en la columna COLUMN_NAME sean todos iguales, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:
# Suponiendo que la columna se llama COLUMN_NAME y que tu dataframe es MLMAR
MLMAR <- MLMAR[!grepl("^(.)\\1*$", as.character(MLMAR$COLUMN_NAME)), ]

Explicación:

grepl() busca si hay coincidencias entre un patrón y los elementos de un vector de caracteres. En este caso, el patrón que estamos buscando es ^(.)\1*$.
^ y $ son anclas que marcan el inicio y el final de la cadena respectivamente, asegurando que toda la cadena se ajuste al patrón.
(.) captura un único carácter.
\\1* busca cero o más repeticiones del mismo carácter capturado anteriormente.

Por lo tanto, esta expresión regular busca cualquier cadena donde todos los caracteres sean iguales.

Una alternativa sin usar expresiones regulares:
x <- 'aaaaaa'

length(rle(strsplit(x, '')[[1]])$values) == 1
TRUE


Con strsplit se divide la cadena en caracteres
Con rle obtenemos los grupos secuenciales de caracteres, si hay uno solo, todos los caracteres son los mismos

